# How to mage git rename already commited deleted and added file?

Tags: git, gerrit

I use gerrit.
I first created a copy of a FooService -> to BarService, changed it and commited it.
Later I Removed FooService, commited it.
FooService is visible in gerrit as deleted, BarService as Added.
How can I fix it, to be visible as renamed FooService->BarService, before I merge my change?

Comment: Note that removed-and-added, and renamed, are *the same thing* in Git. It's the viewer viewing the change that controls whether you see it as "remove old, add new" or "rename old to new".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you made too many changes in the original file so Gerrit (Git) is unable to recognize it. You can divide your change into two commits (changes in Gerrit): first, rename the file, and after that make the changes.

Comment: But how can I recover now? I have already commited my changes.

Comment: Abandon the change in Gerrit through the Gerrit UI, go to your local repository and redo the original change but divided into two commits and push them to Gerrit.

Comment: Probably yes, meanwhile even "renamed" appeared in git status, but later it disappeared and deleted and added appeared. Probably because as you wrote because of too many changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use apprpriate tool for that.

`git mv` command is excellent to do that. Just use it from command line:

```
git mv FooService BarService
```

It will surely prevent you from running into issues like you have.

**RECOVERY**

To recover deleted file (obviously, this change must be seen by GIT), just use:

```
git checkout HEAD FooService
```

This will recover deleted file (more precisely, it will change file to state from revision passed as argument, `HEAD` in this case). With `BarService` - simply delete it from the system file or using `git rm` command.

After recovery use `git mv` as mentioned.

Comment: In future yes, but how can I recover now?

Comment: @bastiat Do not forget to accept the answer which helped you :)

Comment: git checkout HEAD src/path/to/File.java results in pathspec ... did not match any file(s) known to git, I give up and will just merge it as is

Comment: @bastiat You need to pass path to a file RELATIVE to your repo. Treat repo as separate file system :) Git knows only what located in its repo, not everything on your machine (which would need full path).

Comment: of course, this is what I tried src is a src directory in my project, path/to/file is package
so or so, I gave up and merged as is. I tried with checkout, with reset no result. Once even there appeared rename in git status, but later it disappeared - possibly because of too many changes. I suppose I had to commit rename in separate commit, without changing content, and only later in next commit I should change conten. I did everything in one commit, and there is no rename. I will be to blame for whole file and history is lost.

Comment: As @Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira has written.